# Why do I get "stack level too deep" with recursion?

Tags: ruby

I have this ruby code:

```
def get_sum n
    return 0 if n<1
  (n%3==0 || n%5==0) ? n+get_sum(n-1) : get_sum(n-1) #continue execution
end 

puts get_sum 999
```

Seems to be working for values up until `999`. When I try `9999` it gives me this:

```
stack level too deep (SystemStackError)
```

So, I added this:

```
RubyVM::InstructionSequence.compile_option = {
  :tailcall_optimization => true,
  :trace_instruction => false
}
```

but nothing happened.

My ruby version is:

```
ruby 1.9.3p392 (2013-02-22 revision 39386) [x86_64-darwin12.2.1]
```

I also increased the machine's stack size `ulimit -s 32768` which I think is 32MB?

I don't think it is my code's fault as it works with smaller numbers, and I don't think `9999` is a big number.  I have 8GB of RAM and I think it is more than enough. Any ideas/help?

Comment: I think your code is not eligible for tailcall optimization because of `n + get_sum(n - 1)`. Rewrite it with a loop.

Comment: I want to use recursion

Comment: Well, use smaller `n` then :)

Comment: That's the thing, 9999 should not cause a problem. I mean if I used 99999999 I would understand. I think there might be something wrong here

Comment: Yes, there is something wrong: the recursion. Is it a homework? Why don't you want a loop?

Comment: There is nothing wrong, simply that you reached the recusion limit (8731 in my tests with 1.9.3).

Comment: I am just using ruby as a functional language

Comment: On my machine the last working `n` is 9056.

Comment: @TrtTrt: but it's not a functional language.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_(programming_language)
seems to be on wiki

Comment: Ruby is an imperative language that allows to write a lot of code in functional style, but it's definitely not a functional language (where immutability of values is a key point).

Comment: Stack is usually limited to something like hundreds kilobytes, so the fact you have 8GB RAM is irrelevant.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your method cannot take advantage of tail-call optimization (TCO) because it's not [tail-recursive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call), the last expression of the method should be a call to the method itself, `get_sum`. So there is nothing wrong, simply you reached the recursion limit. With Ruby 1.9.3, that limit is:

```
def recursive(x)
  puts(x)
  recursive(x+1)
end

recursive(0)
...
8731
```

This method, on the other hand, is tail-recursive:

```
def self.get_sum_tc(n, acc = 0)
  if n < 1
    acc
  else
    get_sum_tc(n - 1, acc + ((n % 3 == 0 || n % 5 == 0) ? n : 0))
  end
end
```

Your Ruby may or may not support it. In Ruby you can use recursion when you have some certainties about the depth-level you'll reach, but it's definitely not idiomatic to loop over a collection of unknown size. You usually have other abstractions for this kind of tasks, for example:

```
(1..9999).select { |x| x % 5 == 0 || x % 3 == 0 }.reduce(0, :+)
```

Comment: tail-recursive ?? What do you mean?

Answer (score 5):

The problem is, you have a routine `n+get_sum(n-1)`, when n has common factors 3 or 5, Ruby goes ahead to this routine. This cannot be optimized by tail-recursion. Ruby has to keep the current frame to remember the current `n` and only when `get_sum(n-1)` is computed can Ruby return and throw away the frame.

Generally, the stack space is expensive. By default, the operating system reserves fixed amount of stack space (say 1M, or maybe less) for each thread. This can be consumed up quickly. For your code, `(9999/3 + 9999/5)` recursive calls consumed all the stack space.

If you want to keep the recursive programming pattern, you have to change the behavior of your method call from recursive (your current state) to iterative.

```rb
def get_sum(n, sum = 0)
  return sum if n < 1
  if n % 3 == 0 || n % 5 == 0
    get_sum(n - 1, sum + n)
  else
    get_sum(n - 1, sum)
  end
end
```

However, it seems that Ruby's tail recursion optimization isn't that powerful. For the above code sample, there are two different `get_sum()` tail calls. Ruby won't optimize this. You'll have to rewrite the two calls into one.

And besides, to make this work with the `RubyVM` tweak you have provided, you have to load the method definition at runtime. That's because the `RubyVM` tweak happens at runtime. You can't put the method definition directly in the same file, or the method will be parsed at compile time and no optimization will take effect.

You can either put the `get_sum` in a separate file and `require` that lib after the `RubyVM` tweak:

```rb
# file: test_lib.rb
def get_sum(n, sum = 0)
  if n < 1
    sum
  else
    get_sum(n - 1, sum + (n % 3 == 0 || n % 5 == 0 ? n : 0))
  end
end
# eof

# file: test.rb
RubyVM::InstructionSequence.compile_option = {
  :tailcall_optimization => true,
  :trace_instruction => false
}

require_relative 'test_lib'

puts get_sum(999999)
```

Or, use `eval` to evaluate the method definition in a String at runtime:

```rb
RubyVM::InstructionSequence.compile_option = {
  :tailcall_optimization => true,
  :trace_instruction => false
}

eval <<END
  def get_sum(n, sum = 0)
    if n < 1
      sum
    else
      get_sum(n - 1, sum + (n % 3 == 0 || n % 5 == 0 ? n : 0))
    end
  end
END

puts get_sum(990000)
```

Comment: check my question, there is a  :tailcall_optimization => true,