# Stack level too deep, even though recursive call is at end of function?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, recursion, pagination, tail-recursion

I am following the advice of the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15788174/why-do-i-get-stack-level-too-deep-with-recursion), and have confirmed that :tailcall_optimization=>true and :trace_instruction=>false, but I'm still getting:

> SystemStackError: stack level too deep
>
> ...
>
> ... 8696 levels...

What am I doing wrong?

```
  def persist_shipments_then_next(prev_data)
    persist_shipments(prev_data)

    next_token = prev_data['NextToken']
    puts next_token
    unless next_token.nil?
      next_data = @client.list_inbound_shipments_by_next_token(
        next_token
      ).parse

      persist_shipments_then_next(next_data)
    end
  end
```

**Update: I removed the following from application.rb and it works WTF?:**

```
RubyVM::InstructionSequence.compile_option = {
  tailcall_optimization: true,
  trace_instruction: false
}
```

Comment: http://www.rubyappcare.com/blog/2016-09-01-debugging-stack-level-too-deep-error-on-rails Hopefully this will help in figuring out the exact reason for the error.

Comment: Check this: http://nithinbekal.com/posts/ruby-tco/. I think is `tailcall_optimizer` what is causing the issue

Answer (score 0):

You need to have some kind of terminating condition for the recursive  function call. You have put that condition as `unless next_token.nil?`, but are you sure `next_token` becomes nil when you are trying to terminate, may be you just need to do `unless next_token`

```
def persist_shipments_then_next(prev_data)
  persist_shipments(prev_data)

  next_token = prev_data['NextToken']
  unless next_token
    next_data = @client.list_inbound_shipments_by_next_token(
      next_token
    ).parse

    persist_shipments_then_next(next_data)
  end
end
```

Comment: Once there is no more data to retrieve, `NextToken` will disapear from `prev_data`. I've confirmed this by hand in the rails console.